# How to select data that is older than 12 months?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as follows;

```
caravan_id, description, date_purchased, special_instructions, health&safety_check, notes
```

`health&safety_check` is a date field.

How can I perform an SQL query for data in this table that returns all rows which have a `health&safety_check` older than 12 months. But if possible one that is based on 12 months, not on today's date such as < 10/12/2011

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:apex-code]?

Comment: Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: 2011/12/10 (yyyy/mm/dd for clarity) _is_ 12 months ago. What do you mean you want 12 months ago but not based on today's date?

Comment: What is your definition of "12 months" if not "1 year?" A month is not a fixed interval of time. There are months with 28 days, 29 days, 30 days, and 31 days.

Comment: @Matt, not knocking your request for absolutely precise requirements I guess (there may be some edge cases where the negligible difference is important) but I'm yet to meet anyone who didn't consider 1 year to be equal to a full set of 12 consecutive calendar months, starting from a particular date of a particular year - i.e. 1-Jan to 1-Jan, or 10-Mar to 10-Mar, or 29-Feb to 28-Feb :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like:

```
select *
from t
where add_months("health&safety_check", 12) < sysdate
```

I assume you don't want to *hardcode* the current date but are happy with using a variable for it.

Jeff, in the comments, makes a good point (although, in Oracle, you can create an index on a function so you can get around the problem).  This is easily fixed:

```
where "health&safety_check" <add_months(sysdate, -12)
```

Comment: this will unnecessarily preclude the usage of an index on `health&safety_check`.

Answer (score 7):

```
select *
from t
where "health&safety_check" < add_months(sysdate, -12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE `health&safety_check` < ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH)
```

ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH) mean this date minus 12 Month, you can use other date field or variable to change NOW().

NOW() mean today.

Comment: This is not valid Oracle syntax.