# PHP check if date is a year old

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to check if a date in my MySQL database is a year older than the current date (the day that the script is run).

I'm not sure how to properly check this. Here's what I have so far:

```
if ($comparableDate is 1 year older than $todaysDate) {
        // delete this row from the database
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Get Database parameters
require_once 'settings.php';

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// Attempt to connect to Database
try {
    $con = new PDO($db_dsn, $db_username, $db_password);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$applications = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Applications")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$todaysDate = getdate();
$todaysDate = $todaysDate[0];

foreach ($applications as $application) {
    $date = $application->dateSubmitted;
    $comparableDate = strtotime($date);

    if ($comparableDate is 1 year older than $todaysDate) {
        // delete this row from the database
    }
}
?>
```

Can anybody help me out with this? Thanks.

Comment: What is not working? Your date from the db? the date for now? your comparison between the two dates?

Comment: Why aren't you doing the check on database level? `SELECT * FROM Applications WHERE dateSubmitted > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`

Comment: What does the column type need to be for that query to work? I set my date to 2012 but my application doesn't seem to get pulled from the database. My date is currently a `timestamp` and looks like `2012-09-10 16:13:44`.

Comment: I'd just use `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), dateSubmitted) > 365` in your mysql query.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807132/how-to-select-data-that-is-older-than-12-months

Comment: N.B. was on the right track I believe, but as far as I can tell, you want `DELETE FROM Applications WHERE dateSubmitted < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR`

Comment: I keep getting this error... `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in /var/www/html/asapweb/deleteApps.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/asapweb/deleteApps.php(14): PDOStatement->fetchAll(5) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/asapweb/deleteApps.php on line 14`

Comment: It seems to work though.. it deletes the row.

Comment: Well, at least we got to the *real* problem after a few comments :) glad you sorted it.

Comment: That error obviously comes from a piece of code that is not shown. I don't see anything related to deleting in here. You may need a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Fred, I used the code that Wrikken posted. That code threw the error I posted.

Comment: *"It seems to work though.. it deletes the row."* - Deletes how?/where? You'll need to edit your question with the code that's taking care of the actual deletion.

Answer (score 3):

using `strtotime` you can, as [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) says, "parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp".

so, your code could be like this:

```
...
foreach ($applications as $application) {
    $comparableDate = strtotime($application->dateSubmitted);

    if ($comparableDate < strtotime('-1 year')) {
        // delete this row from the database
    }
}
```